# Expression Animation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

Is there any kind of animation available for WPF app like expression animation in UWP?

Suppose I want to move a rectangle vertically with my mouse and another rectangle should move horizontally accordingly to the first one.

Comment: Its all there. Just google it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with **WindowsXAMLHost**: it's a new feature, still in development, incorporated in the Windows Community Toolkit.

By using the WindowsXamlHost control, you can add built-in or custom UWP controls to the User Interface (UI) of your WPF or Windows Forms desktop application, even with custom functionalities.

Check the related MSFT Docs here: [UWP controls in Desktop applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-host-controls)

Then get the companion app from the Win Store: [Windows Community Toolkit Sample app](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4TLCQ)

It will be a little bit tricky... but I'm sure that it is possible to do what you requested.

Best regards

Comment: Really? Is that the answer? Host UWP controls inside WPF to avoid working out how to animate WPF controls ???

Comment: @DeanChalk   Well... I presume that there’s no official way to animate WPF controls... but I may be wrong.

Comment: You are wrong, animations are a massive part of WPF, Google it

Comment: @DeanChalk   Yes, but I don’t think it is possible to implement them in WPF as easy as in the UWP framework.  But I may be wrong, who knows?